# Paypal sandbox account deduction not reflecting in account objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, ios9

I am new to paypal integration with objective c.

1. Created the sanbox (buyer account) which have balance approx 100$
2. Had download code from : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/tree/master/SampleApp/PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App
3. ZZAppDelegate.m
    [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{                                                        PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"XXXXXXX"}];
4. Execute the project and able to login with buyer account credential.
5. Click buy button. console show paid successful :

   *Here is your proof of payment:*

`{
       client =
        {
              environment = mock;
              "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.16.3";
             platform = iOS;
             "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
         };
        response =     {
              "create_time" = "2017-04-05T05:49:16Z";
             id = "PAY-NONETWORKPAYIDEXAMPLE123";
             intent = sale;
             state = approved;
         };
         "response_type" = payment;
    }`

But the problem is : I am not able to see this activity in my sandbox account on browser.

1. Do we need to add project APPID in sandbox account if yes ? Where do we need to do it?** 
   APPID :- means apple id (apple bundle identifier) ?
   Or there is some different APPID ?
2. Please help me if there is any steps need to be integrated

Answer (score 1):

If you have added PalPalSDK in application. You have to choose between Sandbox or Production. You have to create AppID for Palpal. You can check there it has sample code also available. 
        If Payment get successful it has delegate method where we can view with Payment successful.

```
 - (void)sendCompletedPaymentToServer:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
        // TODO: Send completedPayment.confirmation to server
        NSLog(@"Here is your proof of payment:\n\n%@\n\nSend this to your server for confirmation and fulfillment.", completedPayment.confirmation);
    }
```

Comment: yogesh Raut Thank you for the reply. How can i get APPID for paypal. I know the delegate method this. but not able to find the how to create app id for paypal.I already have appid of my application.can i use my application appid ?

Comment: Just like facebook, we have to register our app with Paypal and Paypal will generate one AppID for us. You need to visit Paypal site.

Answer (score 0):

**here you can get all the data after paypal payment**

```
 - (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment
{
NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Success!");
self.resultText = [completedPayment description];

[self sendCompletedPaymentToServer:completedPayment]; // Payment was processed successfully; send to server for verification and fulfillment

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}
```